# Can I apply the final keyword to a POD (standard-layout) struct in C++11 ? Should I?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, struct, final

In a C++ project that is full of objects (with proper behaviors) and relatively few of non-object-oriented structs (consisting of only data fields and no methods), I would like to prevent the accidental misuse of these structs, in which one might try to create a class inheriting from it.

According to my understanding, because these "POD" (plain old data) structs do not have a virtual destructor, it is not possible to properly delete a derived class object (if one is allowed to create it) via a pointer of the POD type.

This seems to make a good use case for the C++11 "final" keyword, which marks a class or struct as non-inheritable.

However, I wonder if the "final" keyword causes the struct to become non-POD?

I suspect that the standards documentation may have addressed this issue, but I am not intelligent enough to sift through the very long documentations to find out. Any useful pointers would be welcome.

Note: I am not interested in merely knowing that it passes the compilation of some compiler vendors. Passing compilation do not guarantee:

- Whether the compiled code will execute correctly in all situations (especially when the technique is applied in a larger, more complex project),
- Whether the C++ standards body intends this to be used in this way.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pod final
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

#if 0
class FailsBecauseCannotDeriveFromFinalAnything : public Pod
{
};
#endif

class ContainsSomethingFinalAsMember
{
public:
    ContainsSomethingFinalAsMember() : pod() {}
private:
    Pod pod;
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::is_pod < Pod > :: value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to my understanding, because these "POD" (plain old data) structs do not have a virtual destructor, it is not possible to properly delete a derived class object (if one is allowed to create it) via a pointer of the POD type.

It's not possible given a raw pointer, but it is possible given a smart pointer object, such as `std::shared_ptr` or a `std::unique_ptr` with an appropriate deleter.

Since smart pointers were standardized, there are few excuses to continue following the poor practice of using the `delete` operator manually. Certainly, classes shouldn't be designed around compatibility with the `delete` operator. Each class interface should be designed with its particular uses in mind.

No, it's not a good practice to make every class either `final` or polymorphic.

> However, I wonder if the "final" keyword causes the struct to become non-POD?

No, it's still POD. The requirements for POD are standard layout (in turn requiring no base class, no access specifiers between members, no virtual anything) and trivial special member functions (copy/move constructor, assignment operator, destructor).

However, the purpose of POD-ness is to allow you to use `memcpy` instead of properly constructing objects, which good C++ code would avoid doing.

Comment: "Poor practice of using the `delete` operator"? It makes no sense to use other utilities in some cases. Especially when you can't use the standard library containers.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Smart pointers, particularly `unique_ptr`, are lighter-weight than containers. It's nearly impossible to write an exception-safe `delete` expression that isn't somehow called from a destructor, and a class with such a destructor tends to be like a smart pointer.

Comment: Oh, I agree that you should not be using `new` and `delete` where exceptions are likely to be thrown. Always use RAII and smart pointers then.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : thanks for your answer. Is that deletion safety guaranteed  in general, or only when using `std::make_shared<MostDerived>`, in which the correct deleter function (for `MostDerived`) is captured into the smart pointer?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Since `new` itself usually throws exceptions, that logic is a little inconsistent. Not only that, you'd have to guarantee no exceptions for the entire lifetime of the object. In such cases, particularly for a POD object, stack allocation tends to be more appropriate.

Comment: @rwong `shared_ptr` will always remember the type it was initialized with. `make_shared` is still a good idea, for improved efficiency. For `unique_ptr`, you have to manually specify the deletion/cleanup, e.g. a captureless lambda `[](base *b){delete static_cast<derived *>(b);}`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter `new` will only throw upon unsuccessful memory allocation, so it is irrelevant to the code *after* new as to whether it throws unless you make another call to `new`. Also, if you're in an environment where `new` will throw, you're probably not in an environment where you should use `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Marking a class `final` does not change its POD status. Quoting C++11:

9 [class]:

> 6 A *trivially copyable class* is a class that:
>
> - has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
> - has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
> - has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
> - has a trivial destructor (12.4).
>
> A *trivial class* is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable.
>   [ *Note:* In particular, a trivially copyable or trivial class does not have virtual functions or virtual base
>   classes.*—end note* ]
>
> 7 A *standard-layout class* is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with
>     non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.
>
> 8 A *standard-layout struct* is a standard-layout class defined with the *class-key* `struct` or the *class-key* `class`. ...
>
> 10 A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no
>   non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types). ...

12.1 [class.ctor]

> 5 ... A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer, and
> - all the direct base classes of its class have trivial default constructors, and
> - for all the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such class
>     has a trivial default constructor.
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is *non-trivial.*

12.4 [class.dtor]

> 5 ... A destructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>
> - the destructor is not virtual,
> - all of the direct base classes of its class have trivial destructors, and
> - for all of the non-static data members of its class that are of class type (or array thereof), each such
>     class has a trivial destructor.
>
> Otherwise, the destructor is *non-trivial.*

12.8 [class.copy]

> 12 A copy/move constructor for class `X` is trivial if it is not user-provided and if
>   — class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
>   — the constructor selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
>   — for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the constructor selected
>   to copy/move that member is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move constructor is *non-trivial.*
>
> 25 A copy/move assignment operator for class `X` is trivial if it is not user-provided and if
>
> - class `X` has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and
> - the assignment operator selected to copy/move each direct base class subobject is trivial, and
> - for each non-static data member of `X` that is of class type (or array thereof), the assignment operator
>     selected to copy/move that member is trivial;
>
> otherwise the copy/move assignment operator is *non-trivial.*

As you see, the definition of a POD struct does not take into account whether the class has the *class-virt-specifier* `final`.